# How to improve performance for huge datasets by substitute a "for-loop" and "if-else" clauses

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, for-loop, apply

Dear stackoverflow community,

I'm sitting since quiet a while on one specific dataset, which is rather huge (nrow= ca. 500 million). After a long series of data manipulation, basically the dataset includes the following important columns: "ParticleId", "flag", "Volume" and "reduction".

- The ParticleId is unique and expresses a moving particle through time and space.
- The flag indicates if the particle is inside of a specific zone (YES/NO)
- Each ParticleId has a prior volume (when injected), which is time dependent if the particle is inside or outside this specific zone
- If the particle is inside the specific zone, the previous volume has to be reduced by the corresponding reduction value

I wrote a for-loop with 2 if-else clauses to reduce the volume for each row. The loop is tested and worked perfectly for testing purposes, up to subsets of 20k rows. Unfortunately the performance is decreasing exponentially when applied for the hole dataset (500mio. rows). I tried to apply several vectorized approaches, but it seems that I'm missing something. I would really appreciate your help and ideas for vectorizing this specific problem.

Please find the for-loop and test-dataset below:

```
dataset <- data.frame(1:20)
dataset$ParticleId        <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
dataset$flag      <- c(T,T,T,F,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,T)
dataset$Volume    <- 0.01
dataset$reduction <- c(1.21e-03,1.21e-04,1.21e-03,1.21e-06,1.21e-03,1.21e-03,1.21e-04,1.21e-03,1.21e-06,1.21e-03,1.21e-03,1.21e-04,1.21e-03,1.21e-06,1.21e-03,1.21e-03,1.21e-04,1.21e-03,1.21e-06,1.21e-03)

for(i in 2:nrow(dataset)){
  if(dataset[i,]$flag == TRUE & dataset[i,]$ParticleId == dataset[i-1,]$ParticleId){
    dataset[i,]$Volume <- dataset[i-1,]$Volume - dataset[i-1,]$reduction
  }else{
    if(dataset[i,]$flag == FALSE & dataset[i,]$ParticleId == dataset[i-1,]$ParticleId){
      dataset[i,]$Volume <- dataset[i-1,]$Volume
    }else{
      dataset[i,]$Volume <- dataset[i,]$Volume
    }
   }
 }
```

If needed I can provide a bigger subset of the original data. The creation of the test-dataset provide just an idea how the data could look like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces your desired output and should be quite a bit faster than your initial approach with `for`-loops and `if ..  else ..` statements:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  group_by(ParticleId) %>% 
  mutate(Volume = Volume[1L] - cumsum(lag(reduction, default = 0L)*flag))

#Source: local data frame [20 x 5]
#Groups: ParticleId
#
#   X1.20 ParticleId  flag     Volume reduction
#1      1          1  TRUE 0.01000000  1.21e-03
#2      2          1  TRUE 0.00879000  1.21e-04
#3      3          1  TRUE 0.00866900  1.21e-03
#4      4          1 FALSE 0.00866900  1.21e-06
#5      5          2  TRUE 0.01000000  1.21e-03
#6      6          2  TRUE 0.00879000  1.21e-03
#7      7          2 FALSE 0.00879000  1.21e-04
#8      8          2 FALSE 0.00879000  1.21e-03
#9      9          2  TRUE 0.00758000  1.21e-06
#10    10          3  TRUE 0.01000000  1.21e-03
#11    11          3  TRUE 0.00879000  1.21e-03
#12    12          4  TRUE 0.01000000  1.21e-04
#13    13          4  TRUE 0.00987900  1.21e-03
#14    14          4  TRUE 0.00866900  1.21e-06
#15    15          4 FALSE 0.00866900  1.21e-03
#16    16          4 FALSE 0.00866900  1.21e-03
#17    17          4 FALSE 0.00866900  1.21e-04
#18    18          4 FALSE 0.00866900  1.21e-03
#19    19          4  TRUE 0.00745900  1.21e-06
#20    20          4  TRUE 0.00745779  1.21e-03
```

What this does:

- take the data "dataset"
- group the data by ParticleId (the following operations are then performed for each group)
- `mutate` is used to modify/add columns to the data. In this case, we modify the existing column "Volume". We take the first element of Volume in each group (`Volume[1L]`) and subtract from this value the cumulative sum of `reduction*flag`. Because we multiply `reduction` with `flag`, which is a logical column, reduction is multiplied by 1 whenever `flag` is `TRUE` and it is multiplied by 0 whenever `flag` is `FALSE`. That means, if `flag` is `FALSE`, we subtract 0 (nothing) from the Volume column (i.e. it remains as is). In addition, we use `lag(Volume, default = 0)` because we want to subtract, in each row, the `reduction`-value that was present in the previous (lagging) row. The `default = 0` ensures that, if there is no previous row in a group, i.e. we are operating on the first row of a group, the previous reduction value is assumed to be 0 - and hence, we don't subtract anything from the first row Volume values.
- In case you wonder why I use an L after the numbers (like in `default = 0L`): that is used to denote `integer`-values which use less memory and hence can help speed up code a little bit, since you're working with a considerably large amount of data.

---

My attempt at the same code in data.table (might be even a bit faster):

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dataset), ParticleId)[,
      Volume:=Volume[1L]-cumsum(c(0L, head(reduction, -1L))*flag), ParticleId]
```

I think in the newest version of data.table (1.9.5) you could use `shift` to create the lagged reduction.

The approach is basically the same as in the dplyr solution here. But before we start, we use `setDT()` to convert the data.frame to a `data.table` object and set keys using `setkey()`. The rest is very similar except data.table updates the data by reference (when using `:=`) and instead of `lag(..., default = 0)` we use `c(0, head(reduction, -1))`.

Comment: That's genius. Thanks a lot! I tried your code with my 40k subset and it was done within 1-2 sec. I'll try your improved one (data.table) with the hole dataset, as soon as I manipulated it in the same manner. I'm really thankful, even though I can just roughly understand how you used those functions. Can you suggest some literature to learn this complex combinations?

Comment: I'll add a brief explanation to my answer. In general, you can learn about the packages and their functions by reading their documentation on CRAN ([here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) ). For dplyr, you can also have a look at the [introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and a [cheatsheet](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: @Herbert for `data.table`, we are creating more detailed vignettes. The new [Introduction to data.table](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) should get you started. Links to other vignettes are available [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). The new vignettes will be updated there too. HTH.

Comment: @docendo discimus thanks for your additional information - those helped a lot. Arun thanks for your comment. I'll have a look to the suggested literature. I'll hope those answers will help also other people, since I coudn't find similar solutions by intense web search.